24.04 I get “-“ screen after dependencies missing notice
Chromium browser updated and got the red warning up top. Said dependencies “lib…18” something missing and 2 “mesa” dependencies listed after terminal search for problems. Ran partial update from the pop up dialog box and rebooted as told to do. Followed instruction here:  Why is my ubuntu 16.04.1 black screen after restart?    And now the “Oh no!  something has gone wrong” screen.  What do I do now?
